# Access data bound to Bokeh glyphs using front end javascript

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm trying to associate each of my glyphs with an id and then get a list of the selected glyph ids when a button is clicked.  I need to combine the list of ids with some other user input on the page so using a python callback doesn't work very well.

So far I have been successful in passing my ids through a ColumnDataSource (I didn't find a way to do it with just the patches method), but I'm not sure how to go about getting the ids associated with the glyphs that have been selected.

note the glyph_id field of the ColumnDataSource

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.glpyhs import Patches

output_file("patch.html")

plot = figure(tools="tap", plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    xs = [[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]],
    ys = [[2, 1, 4], [4, 7 , 8, 5]],
    glyph_id = [1, 2]
))

patches = Patches(xs="xs", ys="ys")
plot.add_glyph(source, patches)

show(plot)
```

Edit:

Here's a solution that works using a callback, but has a number of problems, the main one being that it updates the list on every tap event rather than simply getting the list when I need it.

```
source.callback = CustomJS(code="""
    var selected_glyphs = cb_obj['selected']['1d']['indices'];
    var glyph_ids = cb_obj['data']['glyph_id']
    window.selected_glyphs = [];
    selected_glyphs.forEach(function(idx) {
        window.selected_glyphs.push(glyph_ids[idx]);
    });
""")
```

Comment: Question needs a better description of what's trying to be accomplished, and some example code of what's been tried.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what's unclear but I updated with some example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function for getting a handle to models that use `selected`.  A more generic way to get a handle to any model using a `ColumnDataSource` is probably to replace `"selected"` with `"column_names"`, but I haven't tested it.

```
var models = [];
for (var idx in Bokeh.index)
{
    if (Bokeh.index.hasOwnProperty(idx))
    {
        var idx_models = Bokeh.index[idx].model.document._all_models
        for (var model in idx_models)
        {
            if (idx_models.hasOwnProperty(model) && idx_models[model].attributes.hasOwnProperty("selected"))
                models.push(idx_models[model]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I actually ended up implementing my specific event:

```
<button id="get-glyph-ids">Get Glyph Ids</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById("get-glyph-ids").addEventListener("click", function() {
        var selectedGlyphIds = [];
        for (var idx in Bokeh.index)
        {
            if (Bokeh.index.hasOwnProperty(idx))
            {
                var idxModels = Bokeh.index[idx].model.document._all_models;
                for (var modelId in idxModels)
                {
                    if (idxModels.hasOwnProperty(modelId) && idxModels[modelId].attributes.hasOwnProperty("selected"))
                    {
                        var modelGlyphIds = idxModels[modelId].data.glyph_id;
                        idxModels[modelId].selected["1d"]["indices"].forEach(function(glyphIdx){
                            selectedGlyphIds.push(modelGlyphIds[glyphIdx]);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(selectedGlyphIds);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The example below retrieves the current selection from a data source, only whenever a button is pressed, which seems to be what you are asking for (still not 100% sure). It also shows how to use `patches` with an explicitly provided data source.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("patch.html")

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    xs = [[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]],
    ys = [[2, 1, 4], [4, 7 , 8, 5]],
    id = [1, 2]
))

plot = figure(tools="tap", plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.patches('xs', 'ys', source=source)

callback=CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var result = [];
    var selected = source.selected['1d'].indices;
    selected.forEach(function(idx) {
        result.push(source.data.id[idx]);
    });
    alert(result);
""")

button = Button(label='Make Selection and Press Me', callback=callback)

show(column(button, plot))
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like I can make it work.  Is there no easy way to get a handle to the updated source object from the javascript side though?  It would be a lot easier if I could just access it from my own click event.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to do this *without* Bokeh `CustomJS` callbacks? That's the kind of information I was trying to elicit earlier. There is in index of all Bokeh models in a `Bokeh.index` object on the `Bokeh` module, so you could potentially trawl through that looking tor the data source object you are after.

Comment: When you said "using a python callback doesn't work very well" I naturally thought you meant a callback *written* in python, i.e. a real python callback for a Bokeh server app. I guess you meant a `CustomJS` callback? That's what was confusing. Everyone answering here is donating their time, please be precise for their benefit. Perhaps another alternative is to skip python altogether and just use BokehJS directly: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/bokehjs.html

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be difficult.  I genuinely didn't know what wasn't clear about the way I phrased my question.  It's probably apparent that I'm not all that familiar with Bokeh, but overall I've been really impressed with what I've seen so far barring this current difficulty.  The combination of ease of developer use, aesthetics, and end-user UI is something I haven't seen in another data viz library.  So thanks for your work on Bokeh.